# document.getElemebtById.value asignment from php value

Tags: php, getelementbyid

In document.ready function... I want to assign to a element from the page a value obtained from php.

That is my file is php. It starts by obtaining a POST value that I store in a variable

```
<?php
$myvar = $_POST['externalvar'];
...
?>
```

now the HTML starts... in the HEAD section I include jquery files. In the HEAD TAG still, I start a script TAG where I place a function for document.ready (to fire on showpage). Inside this function I want to access an element in the HTML (an input) where I want to place the $myvar value obtained up top in the file...
So I use this line:

```
document.getElementById('idvisit').value = <?php echo $myvar; ?>;
```

But when this line is encountered... nothing below it works anymore in the function. So I assume it is wrong.
What is wrong exactly?
My input in the html, is declared as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idvisit" id="idvisit" value="<?php echo $myvar; ?>">
```

by doing it directly as above, the input receives the value from PHP, but if I rely on the jquery function... the input remains empty and no script below that assigment is being executed.

What should I do to make the assignment work in the script?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('idvisit').value = <?php echo $myvar; ?>;
```

Should probably be

```
document.getElementById('idvisit').value = <?php echo json_encode($myvar); ?>;
```

The problem is that the contents of $myvar are not being presented to javascript as a string and it instead trying to interpret the contents as javascript. the addslashes call should escape any of the special characters in your input.

Comment: or better `document.getElementById('idvisit').value = <?php echo json_encode($myvar); ?>;`

Comment: It does not work. As before, the event fires only if I refresh the page using F5, or refresh... This is really annoying

Comment: I added code in the question. Please try it yourself. (Please notice that I am using a local version of jquery mobile.js script. It is a modified version that helps me keep the header and footer from blinking when scrolling.) Anyway, it's not that the problem. I tried it with the standard CDN and the problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
document.getElementById('idvisit').value = ' <?php echo $myvar; ?> ';
```

Comment: This does not work either. Even more. When testing on my iphone it succeeded to freeze my phone. I mean, I could not stop the app, nor minimize it. I had to hard reset the phone. Awkward...

Comment: If I enclose it in quotes... then I wont get the variable from php now would I? I do not want to pass to that input, the text, but the value of $myvar obtained above ... in the php.

Answer (score 0):

After digging the web, I think I found my solution:
Apparently, when called from another page, using jquery... only the code found in the first page, below the:

```
<div data-role="page" id="visitarea">
```

gets interpreted. So no scripts above the body TAG.
So I moved the script for document.ready function inside the page TAG of my file and now it gets interpreted and fired when document is ready... Interesting. I am sure some of you will find this useful.
Strange though how if I do not use the php tags inside the js function... all goes well. This remains an enigma.